# What is the name for neologisms with associative endings like "Bostonian" and "imagineer"?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

What is the name for that type of word that modifies a noun or verb with an ending to denote someone who is associated with the word stem?

I'm thinking of words like:

- engineer, farmer (ending = "eer", "er")
- Ohioan (ending = "an")
- Michigander, New Yorker (ending = "der", "er")
- Seattleite (ending = "ite", "lite")

Particularly, I'm interested in what you call it when you coin a new such word by adding an ending. For example, Disney's "imagineer". And I'd love to see a compendium of such words that have this property.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but thought it might be worth pointing out that "imagineer" isn't really so much a combination of an existing word with a suffix as it is a portmanteau word combining the beginning of "imagine" with the end of "engineer." Perhaps some of the other neologisms you have in mind are also portmanteau words?

Answer (score 3):

Words such as "farmer" are [agent nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun).

Words such as "Bostonian" are [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "derivation" to me, a kind of word formation process. 
This paper has a good list of the different kinds of affixes that can be added to words in English (as well as Albanian, which might be less relevant to you)

[The Enrichment of the Vocabulary through Word Formation Processes in both English and Albanian Languages](https://www.academia.edu/6620744/Suffixes_in_word-formation_processes_in_scientific_English)

Particularly page 277 and 278 might be what you're looking for.